# Slow and strange network after bittorrent downloads

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I have a rather strange problem, after I have downloaded bittorrent content the network on my computer becomes strange and unresponsive. And I have to reboot the computer to get it to function normally again. By strange and unresponsive I mean that DNS look-ups seems to fail, web images are not downloaded but I can typically load the site if I have the DNS cached. The network is working, only with limited connectivity. I get no errors in device or network manager.

I have 150 mbit line, so when I am downloading torrent the speed is rather high. I haven't seen any strangeness with the network when doing other downloads, which leads me to believe that the higher number of connections involved in bittorrent downloads might have something to do with it.

I am using the on-board LAN driver with is *Marvell Yukon 88E8056*, and my operating system is Windows 7 with all the latest updated. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you seeding the content?

Comment: @ShaunLoftin The error occurs even after I have closed the bittorrent client. And I must restart the computer to get the network working again. Restarting the router does not help, I must restart the computer.

Comment: Are you sure you are existing the client? If you close the frame it still runs. Turning off the computer cancels the process and totally kills the program. Make sure you aren't seeding by disabling it and then when you are done with the program cancel the application and process using Task Manager.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin I manually stop all torrent before closing it, and I've looked in the task manager to see if it still running and it's not. I've even monitored upload traffic, and I have none... I'm using qBittorrent. I think I'll try some other client to see if I have the same issue.

Comment: You can use tools such as Glasswire to view network activity and applications that use the network; this might point to the culprit hogging resources.

Comment: I have a Surface Pro 3 with a Marvell wifi chip (not yours) and I can attest to it being wonky. I presume that passing a lot of traffic through the wifi makes it fall over. Have you tried simply turning off wifi and then turning it on again?

Comment: @w00t This problem occurs on the wired network. Still I am suspecting the Marvell chip, didn't happen when I was using an Intel card...

Answer (score 0):

Just an update; this problem completely disappeared after I installed Windows 10. So I am suspecting it was a driver or service issue.